# Magento installing error in initialization

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

While installing magento 1.9.0.1, I have following errors. Please help me so I could proceed.

```
        Error in file: "/mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/397232/.technobird.com/web/content/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/data/cms_setup/data-install-1.6.0.0.php" - A block identifier with the same properties already exists in     
    the selected store.
     Trace:
        #0 /mnt/stor2-wc1dfw1/397232/.technobird.com/web/content/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
        #1 /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/397232/technobird.com/web/content/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('data-install', '', '1.6.0.0.2')
        #2 /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/397232/technobird.com/web/content/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(289): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installData('1.6.0.0.2')
        #3 /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/397232/.technobird.com/web/content/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(269): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyDataUpdates()
        #4 /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/397232/.technobird.com/web/content/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(351): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates()
        #5 /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/397232/.technobird.com/web/content/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
        #6 /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/397232/
technobird.com/web/content/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
        #7 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem just now trying to set up another Magento.
To get the install to PUSH through I had to use phpmyadmin deleting tables when the setup moaned at me that they already exsisted.
When I got the error you had the only way I could fix it was by deleting contents of "cms_block_store" &  "cms_page" hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I fixed it by going to phpmyadmin and delete duplicated block in cms_block table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a CMS block that caused the issue. This might be a part of a third-party extension. You have to find the block identifier from the error report and try deleting this after backing up the content and other details. Flush caches to re-create the block, and confirm it creates the block.

If this not fixed your problem, go to the script that creating the block and comment the part. You can find the file details from the error report and it might be a SQL script(GRP/EXT/sql/mysqlx-your-headache-file.php).

Make sure that everything works fine after commenting the part.
That's it.